# Listen blob in audio HTML5 with AJAX and PHP AWS Polly

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, amazon-web-services, text-to-speech

I have this issue with AWS Polly, I tried to figure out how to play the blob I create with AJAX and the AudioStream->getContents();

HTML:

```
<body>
    <textarea id="story" name="story"
    rows="5" cols="33">
    It was a dark and stormy night...
    </textarea>
    <audio id="audioplayer" controls preload="none">
        <source id="audiosource" src="" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
    <button id="play">Play</button>
</body>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-oP6HI9z1XaZNBrJURtCoUT5SUnxFr8s3BzRl+cbzUq8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
    jQuery(function ($) {
        $('#play').click(function(){
            let text = $('#story').val();
            const url = 'process.php'

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data:{
                    text: text
                },
                success: function (data){
                    var audioblob = new Blob([data], {type: 'audio/mpeg'});
                    var objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(audioblob);
                    $('#audiosource').attr('src',objectURL);
                    $('#audioplayer').trigger('play');
                }
            })
        });
        
     });
</script>
```

Procces.php:

```
$polly = new Aws\Polly\PollyClient([
    'version' => 'latest',
    'region' => 'us-east-2',
    'credentials' => [
        'key' => 'XXXXXXX',
        'secret' => 'XXXXXX',
        ]
]);

    $text = $_POST['text'];
    
    $result_polly = $polly->synthesizeSpeech([
        'Engine' => 'standard',
        'LanguageCode' => 'es-MX',
        'OutputFormat' => 'mp3',
        'Text' => $text, 
        'TextType' => 'text',
        'VoiceId' => 'Mia', 
    ]);
    
    $result_data = $result_polly->get('AudioStream')->getContents();
    
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding:chunked');
    header('Content-length: ' . strlen($result_data));
    header("Content-Type: audio/mpeg");
    
    echo $result_data;
```

Audio is empty and I don't know why, maybe how I create the blob or the headers for php?
If you have any suggestion on how to fix this, please comment, thanks.

PD: I don't want to save the file, only stream the audio in serve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to tell the AJAX request how to handle the binary data from PHP Try changing your AJAX request like this:

```
  jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#play').click(function(){
        let text = $('#story').val();
        const url = 'process.php'

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data:{
                text: text
            },
            success: function (data){
                var audioblob = new Blob([data], {type: 'audio/mpeg'});
                var objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(audioblob);
                $('#audiosource').attr('src',objectURL);
                $('#audioplayer').trigger('play');
            },
            
            xhrFields: {
                responseType: 'blob'
            },
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
        })
    });

 });
```